# Firefox add-on export variable into page

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've got a Firefox add-on that has a single entry point: a function call that launches an external application.

How do I export that function call into all pages when they're opened (in reality it won't be **every** page, it will be decided on the page URL), so that pages that are aware of my extension can call it?

Note: there's no need for the add-on to call back into the page or access any of the information on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [page-mods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). In the `include` field you can specify the URLs that you want to execute your function, it support table of strings and RegExp. The following example is from the firefox documentation:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScript: 'console.log("Call your function here!");'
});
```

Or if you don't want to attach a script into page's window you can use [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs)
For example:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  console.log('tab is loaded', tab.title, tab.url);
  if(tab.url.indexOf("mozilla") != -1) {
    console.log("Call your function here!")
  }
});
```

Comment: This sounds promising but it's not exactly what I need. My ultimate goal is for a page (that has been coded to invoke my mod) to be able to call a function in my mod. This seems to work the other way around: my mod can affect the scripts running in my page.

Comment: Though maybe I can get these workers to do that too.

Comment: No, I believe `tabs` is better solution if you want something like this. I edited my answer.

Comment: @biziclop may you are looking for `Cu.exportFunction`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.exportFunction What do you think Christos? Or maybe create a Sandbox to mess with stuff inside the website scope from chrome prvielage like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox#Executing_in_current_tab_scope

Comment: In the end it was a combination of `sdk/tabs` (to attach a content script), `exportFunction()` (to inject content script function into page) and `port.emit()` (to propagate function call from content script into main add-on code) that did the trick. So thank you both.